# Android share content click listener

Tags: android, share, android-contentprovider

**Is there a way for set on click listener on android share content?**

[image]

**For example when user click on whatsapp icon we found that.**

**PAY ATTENTION** : as i know we can handle it with custom content provider with a `recycler view` , my question is about native android content provider like pic.

Comment: Try https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT_INTENT_SENDER

Comment: you don't really want a click listener, you really just want to know which one was selected, right ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody , Yes exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
sharebutton.setOnClickListner {
        private fun shareIt() {
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "message to send")
            type = "text/plain"
        }
        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
        startActivity(shareIntent)
}
```

Source: [Sending simple data to other apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send)